# unset element property from array without reference

Tags: php

I have the following function which unset array element's property. During this process, it also unsets from the original array.

Is there any way to update the array element without effecting the original array?

```
private function AccumulateRoles($Roles) {
    $RoleArray = [];
    foreach($Roles as $key => &$Role) {
        array_push($RoleArray, $Role);
        if(isset($RoleArray[$key]->children)) {
           unset($RoleArray[$key]->children); // This effects $Role also.
        }
    }
}
```

`unset($RoleArray[$key]->children);` // This effects `$Role` also.

I don't want to change `$Role`

Comment: Don't use references and clone the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below worked for me perfectly by adding clone

```
private function AccumulateRoles($Roles) {
    $RoleArray = [];
    foreach($Roles as $key => $Role) {
        array_push($RoleArray, clone $Role);
        if(isset($RoleArray[$key]->children)) {
           unset($RoleArray[$key]->children); // This effects $Role also.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using references in your `foreach` so just remove `&` and it will work like you want.

```
private function AccumulateRoles($Roles) {
    $RoleArray = [];
    foreach($Roles as $key => $Role) {
        array_push($RoleArray, $Role);
        if(isset($RoleArray[$key]->children)) {
           unset($RoleArray[$key]->children); // This effects $Role also.
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have a [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to read more about references

Comment: Still facing same issue.

Comment: When you call AccumulateRoles($variable) do you use & like AccumulateRoles(&$variable) ?